# Convoluted bootstrap grid, all items wrapping

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap grid structure where:

1. The 1st item a tablet/desktop logo
2. The 2nd item a mobile logo
3. The 3rd item is the desktop navigation
4. The 4th item is a profile toolbar that's always present
5. And the 5th item is the menu icon for tablet/mobile

.

```
<div class="row">
  <a class="d-none d-md-flex d-lg-flex d-xl-flex col-md-8 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">regular logo</a>
  <a class="d-flex d-lg-none d-xl-none d-md-none col-xs-3 col-sm-2">mobile logo</a>
  <ul class="row d-none d-lg-flex d-xl-flex col-lg-4 col-xl-4">navigation</ul>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-3 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">toolbar</div>
  <div class="d-flex d-lg-none d-xl-none col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-1">mobile/tablet nav icon</div>
</div>
```

When it gets to `col-xs` and everything is on mobile it turns into a col and nothing is in a row anymore. What's causing this? Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're using `col-xs` I think that `col-xs` is depreciated.